# Why does the Mime boundary string appear at the end of a web service response?

Tags: web-services, soapui, mime, qtp

I sent a request to a AXIS 2 web service in SOAP format using QTP. The response was correct but it had a string appended at the end.

MIME boundaryurnuuid ....followed by a random alphanumEric string.

This same soap request sent using SOAP UI does not generate the MIME string at the end.

Can anyone please tell me why this happens? Is there any way i can avoid this string?